# Preventing creation of fake accounts using email and password auth method

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

1) I've found hourly limit per IP in console => authentication => providers. But it says only for a short period of time up to 7 days. Question: why can't it be permanent? and why default value is 100?

2) Is there such a feature that allows account creation with email and password only from specified domains? wouldn't it be useful?

3) Is there any recommended way to prevent a malicious user from creating multiple accounts / generating too many requests to real users programmatically?

Comment: Yes but it's complicated and can always be beaten.

Comment: Account creation in Firebase Authentication is not limited beyond abuse prevention and what provider you enabled. The ability to create an account is not a security risk, as long as you properly implement authorization checks (e.g. by having the right security rules on your Firebase database).